# I want to delete the child struct when deleting the parent, trying OnDelete Constraint not working in Gorm

Tags: go-gorm, on-delete

I have the following structs:

```
type Report struct {
  ID uuid.UUID
  CreatedAt time.Time
  UpdatedAt time.Time
  Date time.Time
  Rows []Row `gorm:"constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
}

type Row struct {
  ID uuid.UUID
  CreatedAt time.Time
  UpdatedAt time.Time
  ReportID uuid.UUID
  Value string
}
```

And I want to be able to delete the reports like this:

```
db.Where("1 = 1").Delete(&Report{})
```

But I get `pq: update or delete on table "reports" violates foreign key constraint "fk_report_rows_reports" on table "report_rows"`, but should not be Row also be deleted since I added the **OnDelete:CASCADE**?